# CQ5 AEM: how to get a component by name within a dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I know this will probably a simple question, but I'm new to CQ5 and AEM in general.

I have a cq:Widget node which is a simple textfield.

```
 <rowtitlevalue
     jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
     fieldLabel="Row Title Value"
     name="./rowtitlevalue"
     xtype="textfield"
     disabled="true"/>
```

Now at the moment within my JavaScript, I'm currently accessing it via

```
var textfield = panel.findByType('textfield')[1];
```

which works fine (there's another textfield before this one, hence the 1 in the array.

MY QUESTION:
how do I look for this field using it's NAME attribute within my javascript.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I'm using this object to run the following:

```
if (show != undefined) {
    textfield.enable();
    textfield.show();
}
else if (show == undefined) {
    textfield.disable();
    textfield.hide();
}
```

The JavaScript is located within the Component Based ClientLibs.

And this is the Listener that I have under the checkbox that defines the value of SHOW within the javascript (which is working fine).

```
<listeners
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
loadcontent="function(field,rec,path){Ejst.toggleRowTitle(field);}"
selectionchanged="function(field,value){Ejst.toggleRowTitle(field);}"/>
```

Please let me know if you see any problems with this.

Appreciate it in advance

Comment: where are u using this javascript? In the dialog's listener?

Comment: the javascript is in the component based ClientLib.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [CQ.Dialog API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.Dialog) defines the `getField( String name)` method which returns a field with the given name. In case more than one field with the same name exists, it returns an array of those fields.

Thus finding parent of xtype `dialog` instead of `panel` as shown below would solve this.

```
Ejst.toggleRowTitle = function(checkbox) {
    var dlg = checkbox.findParentByType('dialog');
    var rowTitleField = dlg.getField('./rowtitlevalue');
    // perform required operation on rowTitleField
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Straight to the point. Clear and precise. Which API defines the getField method for future Reference?

Answer (score 1):

i did something like that a few days ago and my solution was to make a `js` file on the same level of the component and with the same name of the component with the information that i need.
Something like this:
The file will be called `rowtitlevalue.js` and the content would be:

```
 "use strict";

    use(function() {

        var data = {};
        data.rowtitlevalueData = properties.get("rowtitlevalue");
        //more properties if needed...

        return  {
           data: data 
        }
    });
```

then where i need to use it in javascript, i need the following tags:

```
<sly data-sly-use.data="rowtitlevalue.js">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVariable = ${data.rowtitlevalueData};
   </script>

</sly>
```